# laravel 5.6 validation in multiple language

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to switch the locale into another language when outputting the error message. Right now, the default is always the default language in English.

Inside my route file, I've got:

```
Route::get('/{locale}/contact', [
    'uses' => 'ContactController@create' ])->name('contact');

Route::post('/contact', [
    'uses' => 'ContactController@store' ]);
```

Inside the ContactController:

```
public function store(ContactFormRequest $request)
{
  ... ... ...
}
```

Inside the ContactFormRequest, if I add "App::getLocale('tc'), it will change the validation language into 'tc', instead of the default english 'en'.

```
class ContactFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        App::getLocale('tc');

        return [
                'name' => 'required',
                'message' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required_without:number',
                'number' => 'required_without:email',
            ];
    }
}
```

My question is how I can detect the locale and pass the current locale into the ContactFormRequest in order to switch to different validation languages.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this section in the [laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#custom-error-messages).

You can either use custom inline messages, or even better you can create your own validation files for different languages `resources/lang/xx/validation.php`